# Direct link to the Amazon S3 file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I have setuped the Amazon S3 bucket, its totally private. (You can view the content only if you have console account).

The issue is that I need somehow to create a permanent links to the files stored (as dropbox do, when I click public link). May be it is possible by passing some access token, or smth like that

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "Signed URL", however it won't be permanent.

A signed URL is basically a URL that has a Policy and a Signature encoded in the URL.
The Policy defines which S3 API call is allowed to be called on this particular object - in this case it would be the GetObject API Call.
The signature is then used to authenticate with the S3 API that whomever generated the URL, had the correct permissions to call GetObject.

Additionally, you need to provide an expiry date for when this URL will expire, you can set this far off in the future, but it cannot be permanent.

The full documenation is available here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html